# Does considering only a-zA-Z and digits for training and testing makes sense?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, svm, data-mining

I am creating text classifier for stock related news articles. I use entire text in the article for training and testing.

I saw approach, where person apply preprocessing on the text i.e. `using regex consider only a-zA-Z0-9 and replace rest of the characters with space " ".

Which approach is correct? Does this extrac pre-processing makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In most examples, they remove many characters and In some situation(depending to your data) it can reduce dimensions(e.g for the Bag Of Words model with TF-IDF) and thus give you better result. But in somewhere else, you must consider some other characters like punctuation.

For example you want to check if a sentence is a question sentence or not(with classification), Then it is almost essential to consider punctuation like "?".

At last, think of your data, then try use different prepossessing models and compare the final result(e.g the cross validation for classification) to each other, and choose best model.